# Swift: check if jsonObjectWithData is json or not

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I have a swift application that communicates by http with a server,

The answers I get by this server may be json, or not. I need to check what they are to print the answer as a `Dictionary` or as an `Array`, in order to avoid the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at the `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary`

This is my `jsonObjectWithData`:

```
var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error:nil)!
elimResponse = response?.description        
elim = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

What I try to get is something like:

```
if dataVal is Json{
    elim = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    println(elimJson)
    }else{
    elim = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray
    println(elim)
    }
```

Thank you for your help. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the casts in an `if let` like this:

```
if let elim = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
    println("elim is a dictionary")
    println(elim)
} else if let elim = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSArray {
    println("elim is an array")
    println(elim)
} else {
    println("dataVal is not valid JSON data")
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 2.0**

```
do {
    if let elim = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        print("elim is a dictionary")
        print(elim)
    } else if let elim = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSArray {
        print("elim is an array")
        print(elim)
    } else {
        print("dataVal is not valid JSON data")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I'll try this solution, I have some errors at the moment. elim is already initialized, I can't do an `if let` and if I only do a `if elim` It doesn't work, elim isn't recognized, I try to solve this.

Comment: Well, just replace your previous initialization with this one? I don't see the problem. You asked for a way to test, and this is the way to test. :) Anyway, if your `elim` was already initialized it would mean that it was successfully created and then you wouldn't need to test if you can create it, wouldn't you?... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this for Swift 3.0 and Its working for me.

```
func isValidJson(check data:Data) -> Bool
    {
        do{
        if let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
           return true
        } else if let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSArray {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            return false
        }

    }
```